# Explain why JNLP is no longer a preferred way of installation for jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jnlp

I need explanation about above question ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is not secured process so it is not used in many situations.If IP address of system changes we need to make again the hole process.